# Fletcher-Reeves Method

Tags: mathematical-optimization, programming

I'm trying to implement the Fletcher-Reeves Method, the code is:

```
f[x_, y_] := x - y + 2*x^2 + 2*x*y + y^2;
x[1] = 0;
y[1] = 0;
ϵ = 10.^-8;
k = 1;
grad = Grad[f[x, y], {x, y}];
J = grad /. {x -> x[1], y -> y[1]};
S = -J;
While[Norm[S] > ϵ,
 g = f[x, y] /. {x -> x[k] + λ*S[[1]], 
    y -> y[k] + λ*S[[2]]};
 novo = {x[k], y[k]};
 eqlamb = D[g, λ];
 lamb = Solve[eqlamb == 0, λ][[1, 1, 2]];
 x[k + 1] = novo[1] + lamb*S[[1]];
 y[k + 1] = novo[2] + lamb*S[[2]];
 Jold = grad /. {x -> x[k], y -> y[k]};
 k++;
 Jnew = grad /. {x -> x[k], y -> y[k]};
 S = -Jnew + (Norm[Jnew])^2/(Norm[Jold])^2*S;
 Print["The number of iterations = ", k]
  Print["x = ", x[k + 1], " ", "y = ", y[k + 1]]]
```

But, when I run the code, the answer does not appear, any suggestion?

Comment: Could you upload your code, and not image?

Comment: Forcing people to retype all the code will markedly decrease the chances that anyone will be interested in helping you. Instead of attaching a screenshot, select all the code, right-click and select "Copy As > Input Text", and paste the code in your question.

Comment: try adding a ";" after the `While[]` loop and see if this helps. As others said, hard to use code posted as image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There were just small misprints, after correcting it seems to work, however, check `λ`:

```
f[x_, y_] := x - y + 2*x^2 + 2*x*y + y^2;
x[1] = 0;
y[1] = 0;
ϵ = 10.^-8;
k = 1;
grad = Grad[f[x, y], {x, y}];
J = grad /. {x -> x[1], y -> y[1]};
S = -J;
While[Norm[S] > ϵ, 
 g = f[x, y] /. {x -> x[k] + λ*S[[1]], y -> y[k] + λ*S[[2]]};
 novo = {x[k], y[k]};
 eqlamb = D[g, λ];
 lamb = Solve[eqlamb == 0, λ][[1, 1, 2]];
 x[k + 1] = novo[[1]] + lamb*S[[1]];
 y[k + 1] = novo[[2]] + lamb*S[[2]];
 Jold = grad /. {x -> x[k], y -> y[k]};
 k++;
 Jnew = grad /. {x -> x[k], y -> y[k]};
 S = -Jnew + (Norm[Jnew])^2/(Norm[Jold])^2*S;
 Print["The number of iterations = ", k];
  Print["x = ", x[k], " ", "y = ", y[k]]
 ]
```

Comment: Thanks yarchik !, it works, really the output it was x[k] and y[k], and few modifications using part (novo) of the code. My best regards from Brazil.